# Firebase - Debug and log events on iOS without a workspace

Tags: ios, firebase, firebase-analytics

I am trying to see the log of Firebase events in an .app file of an iOS app.

I do not have access to the workspace, so I am not able to follow the documentation [[1]](https://firebase.google.com/docs/analytics/ios/events) [[2]](https://firebase.google.com/docs/analytics/debugview), specifically 
"In the scheme, in Run, in the Arguments Passed On Launch section, add -FIRAnalyticsDebugEnabled."

Instead, I am trying to load the simulator with the relevant argument pointing to the specific DeviceUDID, then installing the relevantApp

```
open /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Applications/Simulator.app 
  --args -FIRAnalyticsDebugEnabled  -CurrentDeviceUDID CC5D3A12-36E8-4656-A9DD-95F1826872AA

xcrun simctl install booted /Users/S/Downloads/myApp.app
```

When I run this, I am not seeing what I would expect (compared to Android), in the system.log (Debug > Open System log).

Am I going about this in the correct way? Or is this not possible without the actual workspace?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firebase support responded saying that it is not possible as of the moment.